# What is the correct terminology of XML's elements?

Tags: xml, soap, terminology, definition

I am working on a SOAP app, and since it basically uses XML as it's data container, I became curious on what the correct terms for the XML elements are.

For example we have header, body, envelope, but what are is the soap actions called?

I am specifically wondering what the `<something_something>` field is called?

And inside a soap action one can also find keys and their values such as for example `<thisIsAKey>andThisIsItsValue</thisIsAKey>`

What is `<thisIsAKey></thisIsAKey>` called and what is `andThisIsItsValue` value called?

Are they called just keys and values or what?

I tried to google for `XML Protocol`.

Comment: Anything in `<>` is called a tag in XML or HTML. The first one I would call the opening tag and the `</>` i would call the closing tag. I would call the text between the tags the value. In Javascript, the content between two tags is called innerHTML or innerText

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look to the [W3C XML Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/) for answers regarding proper terminology for XML elements and attributes:

> [Definition: Each [XML document](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-xml-doc) contains one or more **elements**, the
>   boundaries of which are either delimited by [start-tags](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-stag) and [end-tags](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-etag),
>   or, for [empty](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-empty) elements, by an [empty-element tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-eetag). Each element has a
>   type, identified by name, sometimes called its "generic identifier"
>   (GI), and may have a set of attribute specifications.] Each attribute
>   specification has a [name](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-attrname) and a [value](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-attrval).

So, for your example, with an attribute added:

- ***Element***: `<thisIsAKey attrname="attrval">andThisIsItsValue</thisIsAKey>`
- ***Element name***: `thisIsAKey`
- ***Start tag***: `<thisIsAKey>`
- ***End tag***: `</thisIsAKey>`
- ***Content***: andThisIsItsValue
- ***Attribute***: `attrname="attrval"`
- ***Attribute name***: `attrname`
- ***Attribute value***: `attrval`